# c# проект с c++ библиотекой не запускается без VS

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

Есть проект, который использует *CefSharp*. Для корректной работы этой библиотеки нужен *c++ redistributable*. Он у меня установлен.
Однако если этот проект скинуть другому человеку, то у него программа не идет, пишет что ***библиотека CefSharp не найдена***. Даже после установки *c++ redistributable* у человека не идет программа. Однако, если он установит *VS*, то начинает все корректно работать.

Прочитал, что динамическую библиотеку надо переделать в статичную а-ля:

```
Configuration Properties -> C\C++ -> Code Generation
```

Но такой функции в *VS2015* не нашел.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если "Даже после установки c++ redistributable у человека не идет программа." значит не тот vcredist установлен. Опция статической линковки в 2015 студии есть, и она именно там где вы и написали. Итого два варианта: ставить нужный vcredist или линковать CefSharp статически.

Comment: Посмотрите программой типа *Dependency Walker* какие библиотеки требуются для приложения и добавьте их в состав Вашего дистрибутива.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а как это сделать статически? Спасибо

Comment: @alexander ну вы же сами пишете путь к настройкам. Там и сделать

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов дело в том, что в VS2015 не нашел такой настройки, хотя все переробовал

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Дело в том, что проект то C#, а не c++

Comment: @alexander А библиотека-то плюсовая, вот и линкуйте ее статически